# How to debug "precondition failure" in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, swiftui

I'm building a SwiftUI App on Xcode 11 but is terminating immediately whenever I switch to a particular tab in the app.

Thing is, it always points to the `Application Delegate` file, which I think is not really the problem. I'm also getting this error in the console `precondition failure: invalid input index: 2` and that's it, no more additional details on what file, array, or function this error is coming from.

[image]

Is there any way in Xcode to isolate which is causing this problem?

Comment: Print what is displayed in console? It seems like there is maybe an index out of range error. Check the any arrays you may have at your destination view controller. Or just check that that ViewController you are navigating to with the Tab is initialized and in the tabController.viewControllers array.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, for the initialization, I'm sure my views are initialized properly. And yes, I'm also thinking it's an array problem, but I don't know which array in which function and in which class, because that view and its subviews are filled with arrays. That's why I want to know how to debug properly. Currently, I'm trying to change many things in my code, hoping I'd hit a fix (even unknowingly).

Comment: I'm getting this, in a very similar situation. For me, the app crashes with the same error and debug console output. It appears to be a C++ precondition failure (so within Swift itself - hence by the breakpoint doesn't work). For me, it happens when trying to access the size of a GeometryProxy.

Comment: Same here - accessing the size of GeometryProxy, to copy into a `@Binding`

Comment: Happens to me to. Next call in the stack is GeometryProxy.size.getter() however it only occurs for me if I access SwiftUI tabs in a certain order. GeometryReader is only used in the tab that causes the crash, (Crash only occurs if that tab is accessed third).

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to the `GeometryProxy.size` crash? Seems to happen if the view is behind another view.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a TabView containing a view that used a List.
When switching tabs, my app was crashing with a similar error:
"precondition failure: attribute failed to set an initial value: 99"
This crashed:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        ListView()
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
            Text("List")
        }
```

Wrapping the ListView in a NavigationView fixed the crash.
I saw this use of NavigationView on "Swift Live – 007 SwiftUI TabView && List" by [Caleb Wells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7910575/caleb-wells).
https://youtu.be/v1A1H1cQowI

https://github.com/calebrwells/A-Swiftly-Tilting-Planet/tree/master/2019/Live%20Streams/TabView%20List

This worked:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView { ListView() }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "list.dash")
            Text("List")
        }
```

Comment: I had same error with `Form` inside a `TabView` that was already inside a `NavigationView`. To work around the crash I had to wrap the `Form` in another dummy `NavigationView` and hide it off-screen with `.padding(.top, -60)`. ‍♂️

Comment: this works, but it is not ideal. I don't want a navigation view.

Comment: My Custom View had List in the NavigationView already. What I did is I removed the NavigationView from my Custom View and added it as you have specified above. After that change, the crash went away.

Comment: @Palimondo I think it should be -100 and not -60. thanks for the fix

Comment: @Imthath I agree with you

Answer (score 12):

I've run into this as well. I just want to share it in case someone finds it useful.

**SHORT ANSWER**

Wrapping my view into a `NavigationView` would raise the error. Using `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` solved my problem.

**LONG ANSWER**

I had something like this:

```
NavigationView {
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        VStack {
            Text("Dummy")
            Spacer()            
            MyView()    // CONTAINS HAS A GEOMETRY READER TOO
                .frame(width: min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height),
                       height: min(proxy.size.width, proxy.size.height)) 
            Spacer()
            Text("Dummy")
        }
    }
}
```

And then, `MyView` had a `GeometryReader` inside too. The code as described would fail. If `NavigationView` was removed, the precondition failure wouldn't happen.

I used `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` on `NavigationView` and that solved my issue.

Comment: Yeah, NavigationView was the issue also in my case

Comment: I wish I could say the same, I put `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` on `NavigationView` but i am still encountering the error

Answer (score 5):

I've had this runtime error on simulators. In my case the problem was `NavigationBarItems`, I used it inside a wrong block as below:

```
NavigationView {
    Group {
        if something {
            
            ScrollView {
                ...
            }//ScrollView
            
        } else {
            ...
        }
        
    }//group
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: self.favoriteItem) // CRASH**
}
```

I moved the `NavigationBarItems` modifier and gave it to `ScrollView`:

```
NavigationView {
        Group {
            if something {
            
            ScrollView {
                ...
            }//ScrollView
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: self.favoriteItem) // NO CRASH**
            
        } else {
            ...
        }
        
    }//group
}
```

Comment: I also had this crash because the navigationBarItems was inside a wrong block

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I just removed the random id (UUID) from the Identifiable and I fixed my crash

Answer (score 0):

I believe a bug has been filed with Apple
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133958
that concerns GeometryReader crashes
in my case, I get a similar issue with a tabBar and the message "precondition failure: invalid input index: 2" when trying to use the GeometryReader as
`let w = geo.size.width`

I've tried using a guard statement around it... didn't work - maybe I don't grok GUARD.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.
You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: you are correct borchvm - yet humans appreciate validation and additional info - both included in my response.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a TabView which was already inside a NavigationView. In my 4th tab I used a Namespace for animation and after adding Namespace animation it was crashing. I tried removing GeometryReader from  TabView, it worked but had other consequences. I added extra NavigationView in 4th tab, it also worked but also had other consequences. But the most appropriate approach for me was removing a **Spacer()** in the 4th tav. Inside that View where I added Namespace animation there was a Spacer() in the button which push all the view up, I removed that and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting I was using a NavigationView and changed it to a HSplitView and this crash started happening.  As soon as I went back to the NavigationView this went away.

Answer (score 0):

In my case a "precondition failure" arose because I was requesting **AXUI** attributes from my application process on startup:

```swift
ForEach(
     NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications, // Maybe this only works with `.filter(...)` 
     id: \.processIdentifier
) { runningApp in

    // if(runningApp != NSRunningApplication.current) { // This condition made it work for me

    var appAXUI: AXUIElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(runningApp.processIdentifier)
    var element: AnyObject? = nil
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(appAXUI, "someAttr" as CFString, &element)    
}
```