# How to automatically scroll down in swiftui

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to automatically scroll down lists in swiftui when running the app.
For example, like this
[How to make a SwiftUI List scroll automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258846/how-to-make-a-swiftui-list-scroll-automatically)

I've created the app by reference to this.
But I got a bug.
Like attached screenshot..
[image]

I tried to fix it but I couldn't find a method that can solve this.
Somebody help please
Thanks

[image]

Comment: No, I just created the app by reference it because I want the same feature like this. but it doesn't work for me. If you know about that, please help me.Thanks

Comment: https://www.process-one.net/blog/writing-a-custom-scroll-view-with-swiftui-in-a-chat-application/   you should read this it may help you,, you need to spicific what is that input?

Comment: I already read it. but it's scroll with static values. hm.. I'm creating chat view now.So if user type text, it should go up. That's the same action as clicking Add button. What's solution for this?

Comment: you faced precondtion failure: invaled input index:2 I think you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304009/how-to-debug-precondition-failure-in-xcode

Comment: Hi  Abdullah Bahattab, thanks for answer. I saw it but I don't understand well with that.
I attached more screenshot for my code on my posting. please let me know what is wrong.Thanks

Comment: your bug failure index:2 does not aim to one reason so its hard to figure it out. may there is a problem to hieght or width with listview... try to decrease it.

Comment: In my first screenshot the bug disappears when remove .modifier(ViewHeightKey()). of course all function of the app don't works normally.
I think the reason of this bug is what it's in .modifier(ViewHeightKey()). 
Here is code for that.
extension ViewHeightKey: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.background(GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self, value: proxy.size.height)
        })
    }
}
how is it? what's wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214378/discussion-between-anna-s-and-abdullah-bahattab).